# Injecting store brings "Cannot read properties of undefined" on ver5.7/5.3 with Typescript

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I created services/store.js with default export, then I added "@service store;" in route. Right at that line the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at Module.default (webpack://tkl/./services/store.js?:3:107)
    at Resolver._extractDefaultExport (webpack://tkl/../rewritten-packages/ember-resolver.4afe6404/node_modules/ember-resolver/index.js?:389:25)
    at Resolver.resolveOther (webpack://tkl/../rewritten-packages/ember-resolver.4afe6404/node_modules/ember-resolver/index.js?:150:32)
    at Resolver.resolve (webpack://tkl/../rewritten-packages/ember-resolver.4afe6404/node_modules/ember-resolver/index.js?:171:23)
    at resolve (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:725:1)
    at Registry.resolve (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:506:1)
    at Registry.resolve (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:508:1)
    at has (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:738:1)
    at Registry.has (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:588:1)
    at Registry.proto.validateInjections (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:710:1)
    at InternalFactoryManager.create (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:369:1)
    at Proxy.create (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:204:1)
    at instantiateFactory (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:276:1)
    at lookup (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:223:1)
    at Container.lookup (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/container/index.js:121:1)
    at ApplicationInstance.lookup (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/-internals/runtime/lib/mixins/container_proxy.js:19:1)
    at PrivateRouter.getRoute (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/routing/router.js:183:1)
    at UnresolvedRouteInfoByParam.fetchRoute (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:714:1)
    at UnresolvedRouteInfoByParam.get route [as route] (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:648:1)
    at URLTransitionIntent.applyToState (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:1151:1)
    at PrivateRouter.getTransitionByIntent (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:1276:1)
    at PrivateRouter.transitionByIntent (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:1239:1)
    at PrivateRouter.doTransition (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:1357:1)
    at PrivateRouter.handleURL (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/router_js.js:1748:1)
    at Router._doURLTransition (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/routing/router.js:474:1)
    at Router.handleURL (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/routing/router.js:470:1)
    at ApplicationInstance.visit (/var/folders/1w/g50r82q15y31dhfvgqjznd300000gn/T/broccoli-7267293LUmMz80Ulj/out-752-packager_runner_embroider_webpack/assets/@ember/application/instance.js:215:1)
    at EmberApp._visit (/Users/boris/Projects/tkl/node_modules/fastboot/src/ember-app.js:269:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at EmberApp.visit (/Users/boris/Projects/tkl/node_modules/fastboot/src/ember-app.js:329:7)
    at FastBoot.visit (/Users/boris/Projects/tkl/node_modules/fastboot/src/index.js:86:18)
    at /Users/boris/Projects/tkl/node_modules/fastboot-express-middleware/src/index.js:33:20
```

I tried to inject store using getter or somehow debug/google the problem. However, it leads to nowhere. Has someone any ideas about that?

Here's the code that generates the error:

Route:

```
// app/routes/blogposts.ts
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
    
export default class BlogpostsRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
    
  // no matter what is inside this hook and whether it exists at all, no impact on the error
  model(params) {
  }
}
```

Adapter:

```
// app/adapters/blogpost.ts
import RESTAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/rest';
        
export default class BlogpostAdapter extends RESTAdapter {
  host = 'http://localhost:3333';
}
        
declare module 'ember-data/types/registries/adapter' {
  export default interface AdapterRegistry {
    blogpost: BlogpostAdapter;
  }
}
```

Serializer:

```
// app/serializers/blogpost.ts
import RESTSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/rest';
    
export default class BlogpostSerializer extends RESTSerializer {}
    
declare module 'ember-data/types/registries/serializer' {
  export default interface SerializerRegistry {
    blogpost: BlogpostSerializer;
  }
}
```

Service:

```
// app/services/service.js
export { default } from 'ember-data/store';
```

Comment: Please share with us a code snap with a focus on the problem!!

Comment: hello! thanks for asking! can you add some formatting to your post, and perhaps the code that caused the error? thanks!!!

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Yep, sorry for the format. I fixed it and added code snippets to the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The solution is [Fastboot incompatible with modern state of the ecosystem](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/913)

I applied changes from branch "fastboot-broken" which is not merged at this moment of writing this post. Once I did, the problem disappeared.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35835134)

Comment: It is actually NullVoxPopuli's branch "fastboot-broken" that is the answer. The problem was solved one I applied his changes from that branch which is not merged yet. I will mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
// app/services/service.js
export { default } from 'ember-data/store';
```

try renaming this file to

```
// app/services/store.js
import Store from 'ember-data/store';

export default Store;
```

Comment: No, sorry, that's a typo. That comment isn't copied, it was written by me. File name is store.js actually. But it doesn't matter. Even if I delete this store.js at all, I still have the same.

Comment: what happens if you re-add the file and do `import Store from 'ember-data/store'` and then `export default Store;`?

Comment: If I try it like you advise, I get another error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization at Module.default (webpack://tkl/./services/store.js?:3:42)
.......

Comment: The issue disappears once I disable Fastboot.